# Implementing Token and Role Base Authentication Using Spring Boot + JWT+ mongoDB

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

Can any one suggest me another solution or how i can fixed this issue please.and thank's by advance

**cotroller**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.demo.entity.JwtRequest;
import com.example.demo.entity.JwtResponse;
import com.example.demo.service.JwtService;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class JwtController {

    @Autowired
    private JwtService jwtService;

    @PostMapping({"/authenticate"})
    public JwtResponse createJwtToken(@RequestBody JwtRequest jwtRequest) throws Exception {
        return jwtService.createJwtToken(jwtRequest);
    }
}
```

**service**

```
package com.example.demo.service;

import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.demo.dao.UserDao;
import com.example.demo.Util.JwtUtil;
import com.example.demo.entity.User;
import com.example.demo.entity.JwtResponse;
import com.example.demo.entity.JwtRequest;



import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.DisabledException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Service
public class JwtService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public JwtResponse createJwtToken(JwtRequest jwtRequest) throws Exception {
        String userName = jwtRequest.getName();
        String userPassword = jwtRequest.getUser_code();
        authenticate(userName, userPassword);

        UserDetails userDetails = loadUserByUsername(userName);
        String newGeneratedToken = jwtUtil.generateToken(userDetails);

        User user = userDao.findById(userName).get();
        return new JwtResponse(user, newGeneratedToken);
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userDao.findById(username).get();

        if (user != null) {
            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                    user.getName(),
                    user.getUser_code(),
                    getAuthority(user)
            );
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with username: " + username);
        }
    }

    private Set getAuthority(User user) {
        Set<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
        user.getRoles().forEach(role -> {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role.getRoleName()));
        });
        return authorities;
    }
    
    private void authenticate(String userName, String userPassword) throws Exception {
        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userName, userPassword));
        } catch (DisabledException e) {
            throw new Exception("USER_DISABLED");
        } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            throw new Exception("INVALID_CREDENTIALS");
        }
    }
}
```

**WebSecurityConfiguration**

```
package configuration;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService jwtService;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.cors();
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate", "/registerNewUser").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpHeaders.ALLOW).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        ;

        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(jwtService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
}
```

**error**
Description:

Field authenticationManager in com.example.demo.service.JwtService required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' in your configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i too had a same problem i fixed by
declaring name of the bean

```
@Bean(name= BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)        
@Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {        
return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
```